# Faster deploy of a docker image?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, kubernetes

My question is - what are the current best practices for this specific workflow:

1. create an instance with DigitalOcean
2. use it a a kubernates minion
3. download image from docker hub

If I understand it right, the main bottleneck is downloading image from docker hub. Is there a way to make this process faster? Anything else I'm missing here?

Comment: You could pre-fetch the images on all your Kubernetes minions. That way when the application pod starts the images will be present. Another optimization is to run a local docker registry.

Comment: Pre-fetching won't work as the minions are created from scratch. But it looks like a good idea to create an DigitalOcean image with base docker image - thus we can use docker caching.
Yet my questing is - are there any techniques to make docker image download faster?

Comment: Also, are there any tools/ways to measure that download speed? Some logs files I can check, maybe, or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the newly announced Google Container Registry (https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/) in addition to protecting your images with encryption and authentication, it has really excellent download performance world-wide.